# Git command for Synchronize changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, git

In `Visual Studio Code` there is button **`Synchronize changes`**

I think `vs code` tries to do `git pull`  followed by a `git push` when there is no merge conflicts.

Or exists special command for synchronize local ↔ remote changes

Which actually commands is calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code do a `pull` then a `push`. You can see it by using `Show Git Output` action, or use `View` → `Output` and select `Git` in the dropdown.

You can find the `Show Git Output` action in the Command Palette :
[image: Show Git Output from Command Palette]

Or, in the Source Control tab, click on the three dots and at the bottom of the list you have `Show Git Output`.
[image: Show Git Output from Source Control tab]

Comment: Thanks, I don't have button "Show Git Output", but in `View` → `Terminal` exists tab `OUTPUT` and there on the left exists source of outputs. I have there are Git, Tasks, Extensions, .NET and ....

Comment: I have updated the answer to show you how to access to the Show Git Output command